# Angular 5 - Oninit get data - local or remote file

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 5

On my *app.component.ts* I currently have this data:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.data = [
      {cols: 2, rows: 1, y: 0, x: 0},
      {cols: 2, rows: 2, y: 0, x: 2},
      {cols: 1, rows: 1, y: 0, x: 4},
      {cols: 1, rows: 1, y: 0, x: 5},
      {cols: 2, rows: 1, y: 1, x: 0}
    ];

}
```

This works great but I want to put this data on an external file either local or remote.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this can be remove and/or local, I would for consistency use the `HttpClient` to fetch the data. So if it's local, put the data in a json file in assets folder (assuminly you using CLI) and fetch the data from there. Then you do not need to modify anything else than the url to fetch the data if it's remote/local.

**data.json:**

```
[
  {"cols": 2, "rows": 1, "y": 0, "x": 0},
  {...}
]
```

**service.ts**

```
getData() {
  // don't use 'any', type your data instead!
  return this.httpClient.get<any>('./assets/data.json')
}
```

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.getData()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for remote file you can use the httpClient to call it
see [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)